# Unix process file with latest timstamp

Tags: file, unix, feed, timestamp

I'm making a program that will load data into table. I've already created the procedure.
But I'm having a problem with handling the file, since there are multiple files in the directory with different timestamps.

I would like to ask what is the code to detect the LATEST timestamp of the feed and choose that one.

For example, the name of the feed is PRODUCTS_I03_20130429.dat
where "PRODUCTS_I03" is just the name of the feed.

I just want to detect the latest feed through its timestamp.

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Hello, it's in shell script.thanks

Comment: Read about the commands [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) and [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something like this:

```
$ latest=$(echo -e "PRODUCTS_I03_20130429.dat\nPRODUCTS_I03_20130428.dat"|sort -r -t"_" -k3|head -1)
$ echo ${latest%_*}
PRODUCTS_I03
```

It will work only if there is two `_` in the filename. The `echo` is just for test. You should replace it with the patters You want to check, like `ls -1 PRODUCTS_*_*.dat`.

If the timestamp is the same as the date of the file, You could use something like this:

```
$ latest=$(ls -1rt|head -1)
$ echo ${latest%_*}
```

or You can get the real date of the (last modification) timestamp using `state -c %y $latest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shell scripts or command line try "ls -t" or if you want them in reverse order use "ls -tr"

Answer (score 0):

```
 ls *.dat | python -c "import sys,re; print sorted(sys.stdin, key = lambda x: re.search( r'(\d+)\.dat', x).group(1))[-1]"
```

Comment: Hello. Is this possible in shell script? I'm not familiar with the language you used.thanks